# How to customize cart item in magento

Tags: php, magento

How can we customize cart items in magento. I have used custom options but it is not working as intended. All I need is to show some configurable data in cart page and in order page.

Can some one help how can I achieve it.

Edit: To elaborate, along with cart item, type and qty. I want to display supporting text for each item type. I got it working with custom options, but I had to include qty inside custom options which created an issue on cart page during cart update. Now I am looking for some other way by which I can acheive same thing.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.Please elaborate your question or what are you trying to achieve in detail so that other can help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you are trying to edit the product that are in the cart. Hope i am getting you right. For this you just need to have a look at the file **default.phtml** in

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

This phtml file is responsible for displaying the item in the cart. Here you can get the custom options of the product as well. You can edit as per your requirement.

But remember before you edit copy this file to your theme because this is the best practice not to edit the magento's core files.

Hope this will help.